# May be someone can help me NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined

Tags: python, urllib

May be someone can help me NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined:

```
for asu in passe :
    curl = url+asu
    try :
        openurl = urllib.request.urlopen(curl)
        print("_____________________________________________________________")
        print("                                                             ")
        print("\033[92m LIVE : "+curl)
        print("_____________________________________________________________")
    except urllib.error.URLError as msg :
        print ("\033[91m DIE : "+curl)
```

Answer (score 1):

Before the code import urllib module with `import urllib`